# Working with JAVA_HOME pointing to more than one locations?

Tags: java, windows-7, environment-variables, java-home

I have a situation in which I have to work on a project with *Java 1.7* on Windows 7. But, there is a tool `jwsdp-1_6-windows-i586.exe` which is seraching for *Java 1.5* or less to be installed and to work with.

Now, I am in a dilemma of whether to point my `JAVA_HOME` to 1.7 or 1.5. Or am I worrying about it without purpose? How to overcome the issue? Is there any possibility that we can provide `JAVA_HOME` with multiple locations?

Comment: You cannot provide more than one location, but you can provide different JAVA_HOME to different programs.

Comment: how can we achieve it? I mean for **different programs**? Can you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: You can consider [this related Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37180393/why-tomcat8-exe-starts-with-a-java-home-that-is-different-from-java-home-setted?rq=1)

Answer (score 2):

Create a batch file that starts `jwsdp-1_6-windows-i586.exe`:

```
set JAVA_HOME=...path-to-Java-5...
jwsdp-1_6-windows-i586.exe
```

Always invoke the command using the batch file.

If you don't have control over the invocation, here is a trick: Rename the executable and put your batch file in the path as `jwsdp-1_6-windows-i586.cmd`. When the invoker uses `jwsdp-1_6-windows-i586` to execute the command, then this trick will make it use the batch file instead.