# Tomcat 8 instance doesn't start

Tags: tomcat8

Firstly this isn't a similar question as observed earlier, as the issues mentioned with similar titles are not the same as the one that I'm mentioning now!

I've enabled **Debug** to capture logs while the Tomcat container startup is triggered from the Tomcat.exe -> Logging -> Level 'Debug'

Following is the debug logs that I was able to capture the following logs:

```
[2019-06-19 11:30:49] [debug] ( prunsrv.c:1729) [ 8636] Commons Daemon procrun log initialized
[2019-06-19 11:30:49] [info]  ( prunsrv.c:1733) [ 8636] Commons Daemon procrun (1.1.0.0 64-bit) started
[2019-06-19 11:30:49] [info]  ( prunsrv.c:1643) [ 8636] Running 'Tomcat8' Service...
[2019-06-19 11:30:49] [debug] ( prunsrv.c:1417) [ 1044] Inside ServiceMain...
[2019-06-19 11:30:49] [debug] ( prunsrv.c:885 ) [ 1044] reportServiceStatusE: dwCurrentState = 2, dwWin32ExitCode = 0, dwWaitHint = 3000, dwServiceSpecificExitCode = 0
[2019-06-19 11:30:49] [info]  ( prunsrv.c:1175) [ 1044] Starting service...
[2019-06-19 11:30:49] [debug] ( javajni.c:236 ) [ 1044] loading jvm 'C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_171\bin\server\jvm.dll'
[2019-06-19 11:30:49] [debug] ( javajni.c:753 ) [ 1704] Jvm Option[0] -Dcatalina.home=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0_Tomcat8
[2019-06-19 11:30:49] [debug] ( javajni.c:753 ) [ 1704] Jvm Option[1] -Dcatalina.base=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0_Tomcat8
[2019-06-19 11:30:49] [debug] ( javajni.c:753 ) [ 1704] Jvm Option[2] -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0_Tomcat8\temp
[2019-06-19 11:30:49] [debug] ( javajni.c:753 ) [ 1704] Jvm Option[3] -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
[2019-06-19 11:30:49] [debug] ( javajni.c:753 ) [ 1704] Jvm Option[4] -Djava.util.logging.config.file=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0_Tomcat8\conf\logging.properties
[2019-06-19 11:30:49] [debug] ( javajni.c:753 ) [ 1704] Jvm Option[5] -Djava.class.path=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0_Tomcat8\bin\bootstrap.jar;C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0_Tomcat8\bin\tomcat-juli.jar
[2019-06-19 11:30:49] [debug] ( javajni.c:753 ) [ 1704] Jvm Option[6] exit
[2019-06-19 11:30:49] [debug] ( javajni.c:753 ) [ 1704] Jvm Option[7] abort
[2019-06-19 11:30:49] [debug] ( javajni.c:753 ) [ 1704] Jvm Option[8] -Xms512m
[2019-06-19 11:30:49] [debug] ( javajni.c:753 ) [ 1704] Jvm Option[9] -Xmx1024m
[2019-06-19 11:30:49] [debug] ( javajni.c:511 ) [ 1704] JVM aborted
[2019-06-19 11:30:49] [debug] ( prunsrv.c:960 ) [ 1704] Start exit hook called ...
[2019-06-19 11:30:49] [debug] ( prunsrv.c:961 ) [ 1704] VM exit code: 1
```

This is the error that I receive when I attempt to restart the Tomcat service from Windows services!

[image]

How can I resolve the Tomcat startup issue with the above details?
Please do let me know if you need any further details on the same.

**EDIT-1**:
Updated the JAVA_OPTS from Tomcat8w.exe

```
-Dcatalina.home=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0_Tomcat8
-Dcatalina.base=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0_Tomcat8
-Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0_Tomcat8\temp
-Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
-Djava.util.logging.config.file=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0_Tomcat8\conf\logging.properties
```

Comment: How do you start tomcat? what are `CATALINA_OPTS` and `JAVA_OPTS` values?

Comment: @user7294900, updated the question with the details!

Comment: Did you check there https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37180393/why-tomcat8-exe-starts-with-a-java-home-that-is-different-from-java-home-setted

Comment: I'll crosscheck this question @user7294900